# Git does not recognize changes on my files

Tags: git, github

I'm new to using Git and I am having issues with files not being recognized by git. This is happening on any repo initialized locally on any folder in a macOS.

When I initialize a new repo and create a file (via "touch [file name]", for example), git detects the new file and I can stage and commit normally. However, after the first commit has been done, the files committed are ignored onwards: when I make new changes, it seems like git does not track them (I type "git add [file name]" explicitly by name, then "git status" and the console says "nothing to commit, working tree clean").

When I run "git ls-files -v", an H appears next to all my files, so, as far as I understand, they are not marked as “assume-unchanged”.

I have tried some solutions from Stack Overflow, including changing "core.ignorestat" to "false", doing a "reset --hard", "update-index --really-refresh", etc etc etc. Nothing has worked so far. Can someone please assist me with this issue? What is wrong?

**EDIT**: the following is an actual conversation with Git. I create a new folder "Test" and then I initialize a repo inside the folder:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/samuel/Desktop/Clases/Gonzalo/Test/.git/
MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ touch index.html
MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ git add index.html 
MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file: index.html

MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ git commit -m "First Commit"
[master (root-commit) df10f13] First Commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 index.html
```

Up to here, everything is normal. Now I proceed to make changes to index.html and immediately have this conversation with Git:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ git ls-files -v
H index.html
MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ git add index.html 
MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
MacBook-Pro-de-Samuel:Test samuel$ git ls-files -v
H index.html
```

Comment: Does git status literally say "the worktree is clean"? Those exact words?

Comment: @matt No, it doesn't. Sorry. It's a (poor) translation from Spanish. It says the usual message when no changes have been made, whatever the exact message is.

Comment: @matt “Nothing to commit, working tree clean”.

Comment: So is the file added but then if you try to commit nothing happens? Or is every add being committed automatically? Is the history growing?

Comment: @matt The history is not growing, nothing is being commited. I think that, after the first commit, files remain added and git does not track any changes made from that point onwards.

Comment: I'm having real trouble believing this. Could you enact an actual conversation with Git and copy and paste the Terminal contents into your question?

Comment: @matt Done. Tell me if you would like to see something else.

Comment: "Now I proceed to make changes to index.html" I don't see evidence of that part.

Comment: @matt Well, I go to Visual Studio Code, I open “index.html” and type some lines. What kind of evidence do you want?

Comment: You could have said `echo xxx >> index.html`. You could have said `cat index.html`. Also note that this is the first time you've mentioned Visual Studio Code: that could make a difference.

Comment: Hang on a moment, I will add to my answer a little play for you to enact.

Comment: OK, there you go. Try my version of the drama. If that works — and I expect it will — I think we can point the finger at your usage of Visual Studio Code. Also a number of things about your drama cause me to suspect that you are using a rather old version of Git, but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: @matt It works, thank you. Could you suggest what am I possibly doing wrong? The only thing I'm doing is opening index.html in VSC and typing some lines. Shouldn't it work as usual?

Comment: I have no idea and I don't actually care. Perhaps you are forgetting to _save_ after typing some lines. Perhaps Visual Studio Code intervenes in some other way. The point is, I've proved Git is working fine on your machine. Visual Studio Code is not mentioned in your question, and I consider the matter settled. If you have a further questions about Visual Studio Code, tap the Ask Question button at the top right and ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> files being automatically marked as assume-unchanged. When I run "git ls-files -v", an H appears next to all my files.

After `git ls-files -v`, a file marked
`H` does not mean assume-unchanged. That would be `h`. `H` just means normal. Don't worry, be happy.

In any case I do not think `git ls-files` is a very useful command for you to give; I suspect that you think it means something it doesn't. It is much better to rely on `git status`, possibly supplemented by various forms of `git diff` (though in fact the former is merely a nice presentation of two forms of the latter).

---

Here is a little drama illustrating how this should go, starting with the drama you have already provided. I will periodically say `git ls-files -v` but it is not very illuminating; as I have already suggested, it probably does not mean what you think it does. But things like `git status` and `git diff` show the situation quite clearly once we have actually modified a file.

```
% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/mattm1/Desktop/testinggit/.git/
% touch index.html
% git add index.html
% git status
On branch main

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   index.html

% git commit -m "First Commit"
[main (root-commit) 6d7e667] First Commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 index.html
% git ls-files -v
H index.html
% git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
% git add index.html
% git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
% git ls-files -v
H index.html

# up to now, I've been doing exactly what you did
# here comes the new part

% echo xxx >> index.html
% git ls-files -v
H index.html
% git status
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   index.html

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
% git diff HEAD
diff --git a/index.html b/index.html
index e69de29..d6459e0 100644
--- a/index.html
+++ b/index.html
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+xxx
% git add index.html
% git ls-files -v
H index.html
% git status
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   index.html
```

Comment: Oh… Still, git does not recognize changes on my file. I go “git add .”, then “git status” and the console says “the worktree is clean”

Comment: Also tried it. I edited the question to make it a little clearer.